# rejected by cors when using withCredentials, despiete access-control-allow-credentials and origin are set

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors

I'm using AWS lambdas and cloudfront to serve a SPA.
Now that my lambdas are setting a cookie, I want to include that cookie in the requests I made to the backend (the cookie is `HttpOnly` and `Secure`).
Using Axios I set the `withCredentials` option to true and all my request are now being rejected because CORS.
The web app is being served from the main domain, while the backend lambdas are on the usual lambda weird UUID url. The lambdas are returning the proper headers, as you can see in the screenshot: `access-control-allow-origin` is set to the domain the web-app is being served from and `access-control-allow-credentials` is `true`. The screenshot is from the app without the `withCredentials` option activated, so it is being triggered from the web-app 100% sure.
Everything is being served over https with a valid certificate (I want to test this also on localhost, but that is a different story)

[image: headers screenshot]

This is the error I'm getting on the console. One weird thing is that it claims that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set to `''`, which is not true

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://p3doiszvgg.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/sessions' 
from origin 'https://pento.danielo.es' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Is there anything missing?

**EDIT:**

This are the headers that I'm sending. The problem with this headers is that they are obtained without the `withCredentials` flag, because if I add such flag the only headers I can see are the provisional headers.

```
:authority: p3doiszvgg.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
:method: POST
:path: /dev/sessions
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
authorization: Bearer the.bearer.token
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 58
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: https://pento.danielo.es
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://pento.danielo.es/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
```

Here is a provisional headers screenshot:

[image: provisional headers error]

The cookie sent by the server looks something like this:

```
 Set-Cookie: refresh_token=uuid-string-with-letters-numbers; HttpOnly; Secure;
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in your question but you wrote `withCreddentials` instead of `withCredentials`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. In fact, I made that same mistake on the code, then I fixed it and then it started failing. I debugged axios code and I can now see that it is indeed including the with credentials option

Comment: Can you show the request headers? What method? What's your config (allowed methods, headers, ...)?

Comment: sure thing @m02ph3u5 Added to the question

Comment: "the only headers I can see are the provisional headers" - how's that? Also, have you tried using plain XMLHttpRequest or FetchAPI?

Comment: Because when the request fails because CORS it doesn't show you the headers, just the provisional ones. I'll add an screenshot to the issue. I didn't tried using fetch, but Axios  uses XMLHTTPRequest under the hood, I confirmed that by debugging it

Comment: I just tested with fetch API, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem and a temporary solution (I'm not very happy with it).
The problem was not my lambda response, that was correct and including the required headers, the problem was with the preflight request. Your browser will send a preflight request almost for every CORS request you made, and, while that request was being successful it was missing some headers. This can be very confusing because the request that it is failing is your actual request (that is what the browser flags as failed) but the problem is on the preflight response.

To be fair, the error on the console was already pointing this out:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check
```

But it is abit buried, easy to miss and the documentation about it is sparse.

The way I fixed it is by adding some extra props to the CORS definition of my serverless template:

```
  authEcho:
    handler: src/users/me.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: me
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: https://frontend.domain.es
            allowCredentials: true # <-- this is the key part
```

It is not clear on the serverless documentation, but those will be merged with the final response, so you don't need to specify everything or all the headers. The only thing I don't like is that I have to hardcode the origin, while on the actual labmda responses I can calculate it dynamically.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. But I configure cors from api gateway console. Could you tell how may I fix my issue.  I meant where do I add this cresentials in api gateway console https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663075/existing-solutions-not-working-aws-lambda-api-the-value-of-the-access-contro