# Existing solutions not working- (AWS Lambda Api) The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

my lambda function

```
    module.exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
  
  return { statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : 'true',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'mydomain_name',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'content-type,authorization',
          
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Charge processed succesfully!`,
          success:true,
         
        }),
}
}
```

error -"

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Frontend

```
 const config = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Message.cookey_key, "Content-Type":'application/json',withCredentials:true, credentials: 'include' },
        
      };
      await PaymentAppApi.post(`/`,payment_item,config).then((res)=>{
         
         
         responseData = res.data
         console.log(res)
         //console.log(res.data[0]+" cal ki hoi na !!! , , ,!"+res.data)
        
    }).catch((err)=>{ console.log(err," error")})
```

I have seen so many posts on this particular topic. But none of them worked in this case. I have enabled cors and integrated poxy to my api gateway. Option method is not a mock . It is integrated with my lambda function.

Cors value

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods : 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT' 
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers  : 'COntent-Type, Authorization'
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin*  : 'mydomain_name'
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : 'true'
```

How may I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true` (boolean value) instead of `'true'` (string value). That header does not recognize anything other than the boolean `true`.

Related MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials#directives

Answer (score -1):

Ensure the OPTIONS resource is enabled in your API Gateway.